# Is timezone true or false

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I want to prompt the user for a timezone. Then if the server is set to that timezone return true, if not false. I cannot figure out why my code ALWAYS returns false...

Thanks in advance!

```
cls

$InTimeZone = Read-Host -Promt "What Time Zone should this server be in?"

$HostName = $env:Computername

$ServerInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_timezone -ComputerName $HostName

$TimeZone = $ServerInfo.Caption 

If ($InTimeZone -like $TimeZone ){$ResTimeZone = "Validation Passed: Server time zone is $TimeZone"}
Else {$ResTimeZone = "Nope."}

$TimeZone

$ResTimeZone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are incorrect here.

1. The comparison is backwards
2. You're using the incorrect comparison

A better solution would be:

```
If ($TimeZone -match $InTimeZone) {
    $ResTimeZone = "Validation Passed: Server time zone is $TimeZone"
} Else {
    $ResTimeZone = "Nope."
}
```

Comment: Thank you Maestro! That was driving me crazy. Now that I look at it, it seems so simple.